# Troubleshooting windows 2008 shutdown issue

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, group-policy

When I shutdown or reboot a couple of my Windows 2008 servers they hang for a long time and display the messaging **"Shutting down Group Policy Client service ..."**.

This forum [post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverGP/thread/e1954046-3beb-4711-b1f7-5d8bce026331) seems to suggest that this may be related to a buggy shutdown script, but there are no group policies that have shutdown scripts that should be applied to these systems.

Is there any logging that I can enable to identify what is causing the problem  Or, what tools can I use to figure out how to fix this.

If I cannot fix this, is there a way to adjust the amount of time windows waits and retries so I can minimize the length time the system waits?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try turning on verbose Group Policy logging. Create the registry key:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Diagnostics
```

Underneath that key, create a REG_DWORD value named RunDiagnosticLoggingGlobal and set the value to 1.

That will enable verbose group policy logging to the Application Event Log.

The only timeout that Group Policy has that I'm aware of is the timeout for script execution. My gut would've said this was a shutdown script problem, but since you indicate there are no shutdown scripts being applied I guess I'd have to write that guess off.

You say "...that should be applied..." in reference to the shutdown scripts. Have you run an RSoP to be sure? Unless you're the only person managing the GPOs I don't know that I'd trust things to be left as you expect them.

How long is the hang, anyway? The default script timeout is 10 minutes. If you're seeing an exactly 10 minute hang then I'd be double and triple-checking that a shutdown script hasn't gotten assigned. To change that timeout, have a look at the "Maximum wait time for Group Policy scripts" setting in the "Scripts" sub-node of the "System" node of "Administrative Templates" in Group Policy.

Comment: Both the registry tweak and the reminder to check the RSoP where helpful.  It turns out there was a shutdown script, and it was broken on 64bit systems.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the "Services for Network File System" Role, resolved the problem for me.
In my case, the AD granular backup was failing with error: "Unable to NFS mount the required file system."